# Using two different ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have two different ajax calls . First one connects to one method of a web service . if it gets any null value for a specific field then it should call the other method from same web service . Here are the codes ..

```
$.ajax({
url: "webservices/ProdMonitorService.asmx/GetEstTimePrelimFinalCur",
data: "{'myactivity':'" + myactivity + "'}",
dataType: "json",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
async: true,
success: function (data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);

 for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length - 1; i++) {



        var dur_time_formated = '';

        var mytimedur = obj[i].time_duration;

        if (mytimedur != null) {

            dur_time_formated = mytimedur.replace('.000000', '');
        }

        else {
            //only one time check for this

            $.ajax({
                url: "webservices/ProdMonitorService.asmx/GetEstTimePrelimFinalCurTotalProcessing",
                data: "{'myactivity':'" + myactivity + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: true,
                success: function (data2) {
                    var obj2 = jQuery.parseJSON(data2.d);

                    dur_time_formated =  obj2[0].total_processtime.replace('.000000', '');

                   }, error: function (result) {
                    //alert("Error: Please contact administrator for help: " + result.responseText);
                }
            });


        }
```

For the first ajax call , it gets obj[0]......obj[7] but let say obj[0].time_duration comes null then it should go to second ajax call ,but even method "GetEstTimePrelimFinalCurTotalProcessing" returns some result , dur_time_formated   varialbe comes null;, it is not even go thru second ajax call completely after first one.

Should use done function after first one is completed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try "async: false" instead of "async: true" here. This will work in your case.

Comment: in first ajax call or the second ?

Answer (score 0):

bear in mind that ajax call is async. it means that dur_time_formated will be set later after your for-loop. so to solve the problem you can use any array variable outside your loop or sync ajax request

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer . SO you mean instead of using  var dur_time_formated = '';  , i should use var dur_time_formated  = new Array();   or simple var dur_time_formated= [] ;

Comment: it's a little bit complicated to say you exactly without having real data. It would be better if the second ajax request would be synchronously. because it is not known when request is finished so you don't know when you can use your object.